# Implementing Stacks using pointers

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, structure

I am trying to implement Stacks push and pop operations using pointers and structures. This code is giving me error at line 40 (`s->entry=(StackEntry *)malloc(sizeof(StackEntry)*(n+1));`) saying segmentation fault. Please help

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    typedef long int StackEntry ;
    typedef int Boolean;

typedef struct stack{
    int top;
    int size;
    StackEntry *entry; //pointer to dynamic array
}Stack;
Boolean StackEmpty(Stack *s)
{
    return s->top<=0;
}
Boolean StackFull(Stack *s)
{
    return s->top >= s->size;
}
void Error(char *msg)
{
    puts(msg);
}
int StackSize(Stack *s)
{
    return s->top ;
}
void StackTop(StackEntry *item,Stack *s)
{
    *item=s->entry[s->top];
}
void CreateStack(Stack *s,int n)
{
    s->top=0;
    s->size=n;
    s->entry=(StackEntry *)malloc(sizeof(StackEntry)*(n+1)); 
}
void Push(StackEntry item,Stack *s)
{
    if(StackFull(s))
        Error("Stack is full");
    else s->entry[s->top++]=item;
}
int main() {

    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    Stack *s;
    CreateStack(s,n);
    Push(10,s);
    //Push(15,s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: have you checked the value of `n`

Comment: `CreateStack(s,n);` this uses uninitialized variable `s`.

Comment: `Stack *s = malloc(sizeof(Stack));`

Comment: The first argument to CeateStack must be "Stack **". Initially (in "main") "s" is just a pointer pointing to some random position in memory. You then need to allocate memory for "Stack", then start writing values in it.

Comment: Don't cast the return of `malloc()`

Comment: Tip: Be consistent, always make `Stack *s` the first parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your main() function like this:

```
int main() {                            
    int n;            
    scanf("%d",&n);   
    Stack s;          
    CreateStack(&s,n);
    Push(10,&s);      
    //Push(15,s);     
    return 0;         
}
```

As BLUEPIXY noted, `Stack *s` declares a *pointer* to a `Stack` struct, when what you want is a new struct itself. You could also declare the Stack pointer and then malloc memory for it, if you need the struct outside the scope of `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are derefencing `s`, but it isn't initialized.

Replace

```
Stack *s;
CreateStack(s,n);
Push(10,s);
```

with

```
Stack s;
CreateStack(&s,n);
Push(10,&s);
```

or

```
Stack *s = malloc(sizeof(Stack));
CreateStack(s,n);
Push(10,s);
free(s);
```